# SSRS Email Subscription Configuration

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I was trying to configure Sql Server Reporting Services 2008 to send out email when subscriptions were created.  I was running SSRS in Native Mode.  Whenever I tried to create a new email subscription this error message would appear in the log files:

```
library!ReportServer_0-3!14e4!01/30/2009-12:58:52:: Call to GetSystemPermissionsAction().
library!ReportServer_0-3!1684!01/30/2009-12:58:52:: Call to GetPermissionsAction(/Report Folder/Report Name).
library!ReportServer_0-3!14e4!01/30/2009-12:58:52:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.OperationNotSupportedNativeModeException: This operation is not supported on a report server that runs in native mode., ;
 Info: Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.OperationNotSupportedNativeModeException: This operation is not supported on a report server that runs in native mode.
extensionfactory!ReportServer_0-3!14e4!01/30/2009-12:58:52:: e ERROR: Exception caught instantiating Report Server DocumentLibrary report server extension: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.SharePointDeliveryExtension.DocumentLibraryProvider' threw an exception. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.OperationNotSupportedNativeModeException: This operation is not supported on a report server that runs in native mode.
```

Most of [the solutions](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/29844120/reporting--email-deliver.aspx) on [the Internet](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/ead32a3e-ebde-4e3b-8a36-d2b2e023e187/) suggested that the problem was caused by

1. Improper configuration of the
   receiving SMTP server
2. Improper
   configuration of the Email Settings
   in the Reporting Services
   Configuration Manager
3. Using a
   non-domain user as the Execution
   Account

None of these solutions worked for me, however.

Answer (score 5):

I finally got the idea from [an MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159155.aspx) to look at the rsreportingservice.config file.  I noticed that the config file included a SharePoint Delivery Extension even though the SSRS process was running in Native Mode, not SharePoint mode.

```
        <!--<Extension Name="Report Server DocumentLibrary" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.SharePointDeliveryExtension.DocumentLibraryProvider,ReportingServicesSharePointDeliveryExtension">
            <MaxRetries>3</MaxRetries>
            <SecondsBeforeRetry>900</SecondsBeforeRetry>
            <Configuration>
                <DocumentLibraryConfiguration>
                    <ExcludedRenderFormats>
                        <RenderingExtension>HTMLOWC</RenderingExtension>
                        <RenderingExtension>NULL</RenderingExtension>
                        <RenderingExtension>RGDI</RenderingExtension>
                    </ExcludedRenderFormats>
                </DocumentLibraryConfiguration>
            </Configuration>
        </Extension>-->
```

Once I removed this code from the config file and restarted SSRS the email subscriptions worked.

Comment: This XML node would not be parsed by the SSRS engine and therefore would not execute because it is commented out (<!-- -->).

If you found it already commented out, odds are that was not the culprit.  By touching the config file, you just happened to force the RS service application to restart and re-parse the XML config file.

Answer (score 0):

If you a using a Data-Driven subscription, double-check that the 'To' setting is actually set to the column that contains your email addresses. We had it mysteriously change to a different column.

Answer (score 0):

You can also see this error if you are pointing at the SOAP endpoint for Sharepoint Integrated mode, which is typically "ReportService2006.asmx". If you aren't using SSRS integrated with Sharepoint, make sure you are pointing at "ReportService2005.asmx" (yes, even if you are using SQL 2008).

Ref:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/8a40f90f-60e5-4130-984f-dc42032376d4/